# How to interpret and translate a Lottie animation from Kotlin to Java?

Tags: java, kotlin, lottie

I have been trying to translate this Kotlin code to Java since the project is in Java. I am translating by looking into Kotlin syntax. However, there are still others that I am having a hard time understanding.

https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-android/blob/master/LottieSample/src/main/kotlin/com/airbnb/lottie/samples/AppIntroActivity.kt

Specifically:

```
private val animationView: LottieAnimationView by lazy {
    rootView.inflate(R.layout.app_intro_animation_view, false) as LottieAnimationView
}

private val viewPager: LockableViewPager by lazy {
    findViewById<LockableViewPager>(R.id.intro_activity_viewPager)
}

override fun generateFinalButtonBehaviour(): IntroButton.Behaviour {
    return object : IntroButton.Behaviour {
        override fun setActivity(activity: IntroActivity) { finish() }
        override fun getActivity(): IntroActivity? = null
        override fun run() {}
    }
}

private fun setViewPagerScroller() {
    try {
        val scrollerField = ViewPager::class.java.getDeclaredField("mScroller")
        scrollerField.isAccessible = true
        val interpolator = ViewPager::class.java.getDeclaredField("sInterpolator")
        interpolator.isAccessible = true

        val scroller = object : Scroller(this, interpolator.get(null) as Interpolator) {
            override fun startScroll(startX: Int, startY: Int, dx: Int, dy: Int, duration: Int) {
                super.startScroll(startX, startY, dx, dy, duration * 7)
            }
        }
        scrollerField.set(viewPager, scroller)
    } catch (e: NoSuchFieldException) {
        // Do nothing.
    } catch (e: IllegalAccessException) {
        // Do nothing.
    }
}
```

For the `setViewPagerScroller`, I was able to translate the first part.

```
Field scrollerField = ViewPager.class.getDeclaredField("mScroller");
scrollerField.setAccessible(true);

Field interpolator = ViewPager.class.getDeclaredField("sInterpolator");
interpolator.setAccessible(true);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34957430/how-to-convert-a-kotlin-source-file-to-a-java-source-file

Comment: @Murat K. It won't decompile. I tried this so I am currently manually translating the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method setViewPagerScroller uses kotlin [anonymous inner class](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/nested-classes.html#anonymous-inner-classes) syntax. That is the 'object' part which has no real counterpart in java syntax.

```
private void setViewPagerScroller() {
    try {
        Field scrollerField = ViewPager.class.getDeclaredField("mScroller");
        scrollerField.setAccessible(true);

        Field interpolator = ViewPager.class.getDeclaredField("sInterpolator");
        interpolator.setAccessible(true);

        Scroller scroller = new Scroller(this, (android.view.animation.Interpolator) interpolator.get(null)){

            @Override
            public void startScroll(int startX, int startY, int dx, int dy, int duration) {
                super.startScroll(startX, startY, dx, dy, duration * 7);
            }
        }

        scrollerField.set(viewPager, scroller);
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException error) {
        // Do nothing.
    } catch (IllegalAccessException error) {
        // Do nothing.
    }
}
```

And the `as` keyword is like a casting in java. Hopefully you can use this to translate `fun generateFinalButtonBehaviour()`, it contains more of the same.

The [Lazy](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html#lazy) construct unsurprisingly gets more verbose in java. You have to employ discipline to not access the viewpager wrongly if you choose to follow the structure below.

```
private LockableViewPager viewPager;

private LockableViewPager getViewPager(){
    if(viewPager == null){
        // produce viewpager and store in field
    }
    return viewPager;
}
```

You can also use a class to more accurately represent a lazy initialization of your fields. (So that you cannot by mistake access a field which you meant to be lazily initialized) This gets even more verbose but could be worth it.

Comment: Thanks for the help, so that is why I can't google the equivalent of "object : " in java. How about the LottieAnimationView? I can't seem to translate it...     private LottieAnimationView animationView;

    public LottieAnimationView getAnimationView() {
        (ViewGroup)IntroWalkthroughActivity.this.getRootView().inflate(R.layout.activity_intro_app_walkthrough, false);
    }

Comment: Make sure you cast the right objects to the correct classes when needed and that in the end you cast to `LottieAnimationView` and then store it in your field

Comment: Note that `lazy` in Kotlin also ensures thread safety, which a plain `if` in Java wouldn't do. I guess in your case this should be fine because those views are likely only accessed from the main thread, but keep it in mind before deriving a general rule from this translation