# How to convert kotlin to java on android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

recently I study kotlin. first, kotlin is not support `static`.

so I use `companion object`

```
companion object InstanceHolder {
   private val mCamera = MainActivity()

   fun getInstance(): MainActivity {
       return mCamera
   }
}
```

but I want this source convert to java.
How to convert kotlin to java?

thanks

Comment: Why are you holding an instance of Activity?

Answer (score 0):

in IntelliJ or Android Studio, you just have to do the following to get java code from kotlin:

Menu > Tools > Kotlin > Show Kotlin Bytecode
Click on the Decompile button
Copy the java code

Refer this answer in stackoverflow [Convert Kotlin to Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34957430/how-to-convert-a-kotlin-source-file-to-a-java-source-file)

Comment: It's buggy. It freezes my android studio.