# Converting Kotlin to Java

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin, decompiler

Can anyone help me about converting *Kotlin* code in *Android Studio* to *Java*?

I went through the below process:

*Tools >> Kotlin>> Decompile Kotlin to Java*

But the "Kotlin to Java" option is disabled. What should I do?

[image]

Comment: check this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/52983100/4797289

Answer (score 29):

Currently `Tools >> Kotlin>> Decompile Kotlin to Java` is enabled only for compiled *Kotlin* classes (`.class`, not `.kt` extension) located at `app/build/tmp/kotlin-classes/` **after a successful build**.

A note to the [@Uriel Frankel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/588532/uriel-frankel)'s workaround:

*If `Tools >> Kotlin >> Show Kotlin Bytecode >> Decompile button` is disabled (or not shown) the `Java Bytecode Decompiler` plugin should be installed: `Preferences >> Plugins >> search for`Java Bytecode Decompiler` >> check the plugin & press OK*.

Answer (score 8):

Tools >> kotlin >> Show Kotlin bytecode >> Decompile

Comment: At least for me, there is no "Decompile" option in that view.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like a bug.

> `Tools -> Kotlin -> Decompile Kotlin to Java`

Was actually disabled for me too **even after a successful build** (*In my side Android Studio v3.2*) so, I went through this:

Click on the Kotlin (*Compiled class*):

Selected `Tools -> Kotlin -> Show Kotlin Bytecode`

Then kotlin bytecode window appeared:

[image]

Made JVM 8 Target as selected and then decompile gave me the java class.

**Note** that this happened when `Java Bytecode Decompiler` plugin was enabled on the Android Studio.

**Update**:

This however might have some issues even after converting to java and perhaps, we should wait for the newest releases.

Answer (score 0):

I followed Onik's answer above.

The Java Bytecode Decompiler was automatically bundled.
I opened the .class file in Android Studio, and selected  *Tools >> Kotlin>> Decompile Kotlin to Java.*

After waiting several minutes, Android Studio told me

> The file is too large: 50.78 MB.  Showing a read-only preview of the first 2.56 MB

and it opened a file MyKotlinClass.decompiled.java, most of which is unintelligible to me.

MyKotlinClass is approximately **300 lines** long.  At this point, manually re-writing the file as Java code is looking like the better option.