# Decompile Kotlin byte code to java such that variable names be the same?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I know in Android Studio we can decompile Kotlin bytecode to Java from

`Tools->Kotlin->Show Kotlin Bytecode`

and then `Decompile` in the opened window. but the result is somehow messy.
for example in this code, variable names are changed to `var1`,`var2` and so on and missed Generic type in return value type.

the Kotlin code:

```
   @GET("webservicesample")
        fun advancedSearchCall(@Query("parms[catid]") catID: String,
                               @Query("parms[min]") minPrice: String,
                               @Query("parms[max]") maxPrice: String,
                               @Query("parms[brandid]") brandId: String,
                               @Query("parms[minpre]") minPrePay: String,
                               @Query("parms[maxpre]") maxPrePay: String,
                               @Query("parms[id]") lastResult: String,
                               @Query("parms[number]") number: String)
                : Call<AdvancedSearchResponse>
```

Decompiled to Java from bytecode:

```
@GET("webserviceexample")
       @NotNull  Call advancedSearchCall(
                  @Query("parms[catid]") @NotNull String var1, 
                  @Query("parms[min]") @NotNull String var2, 
                  @Query("parms[max]") @NotNull String var3, 
                  @Query("parms[brandid]") @NotNull String var4,
                  @Query("parms[minpre]") @NotNull String var5,
                  @Query("parms[maxpre]") @NotNull String var6,
                  @Query("parms[id]") @NotNull String var7,
                  @Query("parms[number]") @NotNull String var8);
```

I wonder if there is a way to prevent this and get clean Java code when decompiling from Kotlin?

Comment: All names are lost when compiled. There may be a debugging flag to have it compile with names, but that would have to be enabled, and wouldn't be retroactive.

Comment: @Carcigenicate but how is that when pressing shift+ctrl+alt+k for turning Kotlin to Java it keeps variable names?

Comment: If it's transpiling directly from Kotlin to Java, then it has access to the variable names via the Java code. Unless you know that it's decompiling from the Java byte code produced by the Kotlin code.

Comment: @Carcigenicate And there is no way to doing that?

Comment: Unforumately, no. Decompiling is different from transpiling.

Comment: check this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/52983100/4797289