# Bad: Java deobfuscation stack trace

Tags: java, android, kotlin

could you help me?

When developing an application for android for obfuscation, we use a proguard that inserts a mapping file.
After deobfuscation on the mapping file, I get the following stack trace, but instead of the line number I see:

```
(SourceFile: 2).
```

What is the reason for not showing the number of line, and is there any way to get the number of line?

Example stackTrace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerExce: 
  at com.test.app.fragment.TestFragment.onSaveInstanceState (SourceFile:2)
```

In another case, after deobfuscation, instead of the normal stack trace, I get something like this:

```
Caused by: com.test.app.inneral.sdk.internal.uus5: 
  at com.test.app.inneral.sdk.internal.ms4$b.accept (SourceFile:5)
```

What is the reason, it is possible to somehow get a normal stack trace from this?

Answer (score -1):

Java exception messages follow a format of Exception > Package/Class/Method > (Source File:Line Number), so in (SourceFile:2), the exception would be thrown on the 2nd line.

Also, according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52969958/kotlin-code-stack-trace-shows-java-line-numbers) (if you're using an IDE for developing android apps), some IDE's have stack trace analysis tools build in.

I hope this helps!