# Code addon with kotlin and convert the code to java

Tags: java, kotlin

Please i have a question 
Kokotime(media center like kodi) addons are coded in Java
 i want to ask if i can code the addon with kotlin and convert the code to java ?
ps : i'm still learning kotlin (beginner)

Comment: I think you won’t have a problem having it coded in Kotlin

Comment: Using IntelliJ or Android Studio IDE [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34957430/9363973) question and it's answer may help you. Otherwise there is an [online tool](https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/Kotlin%20Koans/Introduction/Java%20to%20Kotlin%20conversion/Task.kt) from kotlinlang itself to help you do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once compiled, kotlin bytecode is identical to java bytecode. Any application that uses compiled programs/addons for the JVM will work with java, kotlin, and any other JVM language.