# Is it possible to convert Kotlin to Java using Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I have a Kotlin project that I need to convert in Java. I don't know if it is possible in Android Studio ?
Can the Kotlin's logics be converted in Java's without loosing anything or having some issues when running the app ?

If YES, how to do it perfectly ?

Comment: Thanks a lot. This question was already answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34957430/how-to-convert-a-kotlin-source-file-to-a-java-source-file

Comment: Just watch out, the decompiled code will look super ugly and disgusting... Trust me, I've tried...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to do the following to get java code from kotlin:

```
Menu > Tools > Kotlin > Show Kotlin Bytecode

Click on the Decompile button

Copy the java code
```

With a version (1.2+) of the Kotlin plugin you also can directly do Menu > Tools > Kotlin -> Decompile Kotlin to Java.

Try to be sure that everythings works fine.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, I find solutions here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34957430/how-to-convert-a-kotlin-source-file-to-a-java-source-file