# Decompile button (kotlin to java) in Android Studio is disappeared?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I'm trying to decompile kotlin code to java.
[This question describes how to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34957430/how-to-convert-a-kotlin-source-file-to-a-java-source-file/54116131#54116131)

I have to see something like this:
[image]

But in fact i see next one. 
[image]

As you can see I do NOT have a "Decompile" button

**Android Studio 3.5**

Can anybody help me please?

Answer (score 2):

Go to Extensions and look for "Java Bytecode Decompiler".
Install it and do a complete restart to the Android Studio. Don't just close and open the project, restart the whole program.

Then, when the Android Studio will pop open again, click on "Search Everywhere" (by clicking shift twice), look for "Java Bytecode Decompiler", and make sure it's turned into ON.

That's it. Now the button should be visible.

Answer (score 2):

make sure you have this plugin enabled, should work after

[image]