# Flutter how to generate Java rather than Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, flutter

I have already advance in my project, but I want to write android-specific code. It is generated in Kotlin by flutter, but I want Java. How can I change this?

Comment: `flutter create --org com.yourpackage -i swift -a kotlin --description 'app name description' your_app_name`

Comment: Maybe create a kotlin project and run it through a kotlin -> java converter

Comment: Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34957430/how-to-convert-a-kotlin-source-file-to-a-java-source-file

Comment: @Blasanka How does linking to a question about Swift, answer a question about Java?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel sorry I didnt get you

Comment: @Blasanka The OP is asking about generating Java from Flutter, and you link to a question to generate Swift from Flutter. How does that help?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel oh ok I got you. Title is different but scroll to second answer. Then you will see the solution for both android and swift

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Even the question is pointing out Android.

Comment: @Blasanka Kotlin is a language for Android, just like Java... And the op doesn't want Kotlin, they want Java.

Comment: Yes @MarkRotteveel I know that, It doesnt matter the environment or the language, in Fluttter framework, this is the command for both: `create --org com.yourpackage -i swift -a kotlin --description 'app name description' your_app_name` I flag it added a comment mentioning this also.

Comment: @Blasanka And that creates a Kotlin application, not a Java application that the OP was asking about.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Common I thinking globaly, cant he just change the language there `kotlin` to `java`???

Answer (score 3):

I finally recreated my project with the following command :

```
flutter create -i swift -a java app_name
```

Comment: Other people helped here. remember to upvote and award @olibsjr the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the command `flutter create . -i swift -a java` in your project directory to convert your current app to swift and java. **Make sure to back up your app first.** It will also repair your project, recreating any files that are missing.

If this doesn't work, you might have to create a new project with the command `flutter create -i objc -a java your_app_name_here`, as mentionned above.