# What does @get:NotNull mean in Kotlin?

Tags: validation, kotlin

I read a code generated by [khipster](https://khipster.dev/) and in one dataclass I found such fragment:

```
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull

data class MyDTO(
    var id: Long? = null,
    @get: NotNull
    var name: String? = null,
```

What does `@get:NotNull` annotation mean? As far as I understand `@get` means that I want to annotate the getter of `name` property and `NotNull` is a validation annotation which mean that the thing can't be set to null. But how the two work together? It doesn't make any sense to annotate getter with annotation which means *this can't be set to null*, because getter can't be set. It would make more sens to use `NotNull` annotation on setter.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the decompile feature of IntelliJ ( please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40762755/1848496) answer )

Kotlin Code:

```
@get: NotNull
var uid: String? = null
```

Decompiled Code:

```
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable;

@Nullable
private String uid;

@NotNull
@Nullable
public final String getUid() {
   return this.uid;
}

public final void setUid(@Nullable String var1) {
   this.uid = var1;
}
```

> What does @get:NotNull annotation mean?

A quick answer: Please put `@NotNull` annotation on the top of the getter function

!! Please be aware that there is also `@Nullable` annotation added to the getter function because of the "?" at the end of the variable definition
As you notice from import it is added by IntelliJ

As detailed answer: I could redirect you to "Use-Site Target Declarations"

- [Bealdung](https://www.baeldung.com/kotlin/annotations#1-use-site-target-declarations)
- [Blog post](https://americanexpress.io/advanced-kotlin-use-site-targets/)

Finally, I would like to express my experience on that, I had both `@Nullable` and `@NotNull` annotation on `uid` field (you could see on decompiled code), I could set that field to `null`

Answer (score 0):

`@NotNull` on a method means it can't *return* `null`. So in particular annotating a setter with it makes no sense; annotating the setter's parameter does.