# Where is the IntelliJ Decompile Button (Converting Kotlin Code to Java)?

Tags: java, kotlin, intellij-idea

I have a Kotlin project that I'd like to convert into Java-Code using IntelliJ. Now I [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34957430/how-to-convert-a-kotlin-source-file-to-a-java-source-file) that all I need to do is:

1. `Menu > Tools > Kotlin > Show Kotlin Bytecode`
2. Click on the Decompile button
3. Copy the java code

So I tried to follow that and have been able to successfully view Kotlin Bytecode - yet I am wondering where the decompile Button is? Sadly I tried searching it in Google and I could not find it - probably I am just blind and it is obvious?

When I go into `Tools > Kotlin` then `Decompile Kotlin to Java` is greyed (in case that is the decompile button that is mentioned everywhere).

Can someone help me out on that?

I am running on IntelliJ Ultimate.

---

**Edit:**

This panel is shown when I press `Show Kotlin Bytecode`:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The `Decompile` button is in the top bar of the `Kotlin Bytecode` panel which opens when you select `Show Kotlin Bytecode`.

Comment: I edited my post and added the panel view I can see